# When hovering over the legend (Google Visualization API), tooltip description appears hidden behind the report

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

1) Is tooltip over legend custom (from Google Visualisation)? I didn't find any information about such tooltips. This tooltip appears when legend is trimmed because is too long.

2) How to make legend tooltip pop-up over card with graph

[when hovering over the legent text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/linxl.png)

[the same situation without background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja0fZ.png)

**When I hover trimmed legend, lib creates div element almost at the end of DOM with class *"charts-tooltyip"*, so css z-index solved my problem, but I am not sure that is optimally decision.**

Comment: did you try adding this to your options? --> `tooltip: {ignoreBounds: true}`

Comment: tooltip: {ignoreBounds: true}
just tried, but didn't work, seems like it's another tooltip which options are not applicable

Comment: Just had the exact same issue and was able to resolve with:
```.goog-tooltip {
        z-index: 10;
      }```